# Convert object to 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How I can transform an object to a 2d array?

for example :

```
{ field : 'name',
  value : 'peter',
  field1 : 'email',
  value1 : 'test@gmail.com',
  field2 : 'id',
  value2 : '2345',
  ............
  .....
  ...
 }
```

to

```
  [['name', 'peter],['email','test@gmail.com'],['id','2345'] .......]
```

thanks!

Comment: Sure, but my English is not good,  I try to find the solution by google search but still no idea on it

Comment: Programming doesn't work like cooking. In most cases there is no ready recipe for your specific problem. You have to find it yourself. Begin from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  field: 'name',
  value: 'peter',
  field1: 'email',
  value1: 'test@gmail.com',
  field2: 'id',
  value2: '2345'
};

let result = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(key => key.indexOf("field") === 0)  // we're only interested in the "fieldX" keys
  .map(field => [obj[field], obj[field.replace("field", "value")]]); // build the array from the "fieldX"-keys

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `field` and get the value for a new array.

```js
var object = { field: 'name', value: 'peter', field1: 'email', value1: 'test@gmail.com', field2: 'id', value2: '2345'},
    array = Object.keys(object).reduce((r, k) => 
        r.concat(k.slice(0, 5) === 'field'? [[object[k], object['value' + k.slice(5)]]] : [])
    , []);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thats not what is required

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let obj = {
      field : 'name',
      value : 'peter',
      field1 : 'email',
      value1 : 'test@gmail.com',
      field2 : 'id',
      value2 : '2345'
    };
    
    let results = [];

    Object.values(obj).forEach((e, i, arr) => {
     if (!(i % 2)) {
      results.push([e, arr[i+1]]);
     }
    });

    console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function, it will do it for you:

```
var objectToPairs = function(object) {
  var array = [];

  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (key.indexOf('field') === 0) {
        var index = key.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
        var valueKey = 'value' + index;

        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          array.push([object[key], object[valueKey]]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

JSFIddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mucwvqpz/1/